# Why Highcharts box only show with some position

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I tried to display text above all series point of Highcharts bar chart.

But it only display box for Hien1 and Hien10.

How to display all box from Hien1 to Hien10?

Here is my code

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   chart: {
            type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        max: 300
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

}, function (chart) {
    for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    var point = chart.series[0].data[i];
        let text = chart.renderer.text(
            'Hien' + i,
            point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 10,
            point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 10
        ).attr({
            zIndex: 5
        }).add();
        let box = text.getBBox();

    chart.renderer.rect(box.x - 5, box.y - 5, box.width + 10, box.height + 10, 5)
        .attr({
            fill: '#FFFFEF',
            stroke: 'gray',
            'stroke-width': 1,
            zIndex: 4
        })
        .add();
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px; width: 400"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same positions of the text in order to position the rectangles:

```
chart.renderer.rect(point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 5, point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 25, box.width + 10, box.height + 10, 5)
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   chart: {
            type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        max: 300
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

}, function (chart) {
    for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        var point = chart.series[0].data[i];
        let text = chart.renderer.text(
            'Hien' + i,
            point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 10,
            point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 10
        ).attr({
            zIndex: 5
        }).add();
        let box = text.getBBox();
        
 chart.renderer.rect(point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 5, point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 25, box.width + 10, box.height + 10, 5)
        .attr({
            fill: '#FFFFEF',
            stroke: 'gray',
            'stroke-width': 1,
            zIndex: 4
        })
        .add();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px; width: 400"></div>
```

Comment: thanks Dekel, can you help me display Hien0 to Hien10 at same level with the highest value?

Comment: If you want to position all of them based on the highest value you need to find the highest value and position everything based on that. What did you try that didn't work for you?

Comment: I did it, thank you http://jsfiddle.net/viethien/zghkrn6e/15/